# MATLAB - Intersection of matrices with same number of rows, different number of columns

Tags: matlab, matrix

how to make the intersection of `10` matrices that have the same number of rows but different number of columns?

The goal is to find common columns for the `10` matrices.

How to reduce these lines:

```
B1 = intersect(A1',A2','rows')';
B2 = intersect(B1',A3','rows')';
B3 = intersect(B2',A4','rows')';
B4 = intersect(B3',A5','rows')';
B5 = intersect(B4',A6','rows')';
B6 = intersect(B5',A7','rows')';
B7 = intersect(B6',A8','rows')';
B8 = intersect(B7',A9','rows')';
B9 = intersect(B8',A10','rows')';
```

Comment: Flip them so they have common rows rather than common columns, stack them and use `unique` with the `rows` option.

Comment: @nkjt: it gives the union, not the intersection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `A1`, `A2`, `A3`....`A10` to be those 10 input matrices, see if this works for you -

```
A = cat(1,{A1},{A2},{A3},.....{A10}) %// concatenate all variables into a cell array
A = cellfun(@(x) x.',A,'uni',0) %//'# transpose each cell, so that number of columns 
                               %// corresponding to all matrices is the same

%// Get intersecting rows for each pair from A and keeping the intersecting output 
%// for comparison against the next one.
out = A{1}; %// iInitiliaze with the first cell that is the first matrix
for iter = 2:numel(A)
    out = intersect(A{iter},out,'rows'); %// find intersection for each matrix 
                                        %// against the running intersection result
end    
result = out.' %//# desired output
```